# Count only visible data after filtering

Tags: excel, vba

I need to add to the below code the ability to only count the visible data after filtering.

I assume it is possibly `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` or similar after `With Worksheet("calculations")`, but I can't figure it out.

```
Sub Count_only_visible_data()
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("E5").Value = Countv("Work", "WSCA1", "Processed")
    .Range("E6").Value = Countv("Work", "WSCA2", "Processed")
    .Range("E7").Value = Countv("Work", "SECA11", "Processed")
    .Range("E8").Value = Countv("Work", "SECA12", "Processed")
    .Range("E9").Value = Countv("Work", "SECA13", "Processed")
    .Range("E17").Value = Countv("Work", "NWCA5", "Processed")
    .Range("E18").Value = Countv("Work", "NWCA6A", "Processed")
    .Range("E19").Value = Countv("Work", "NWCA6B", "Processed")
    .Range("E20").Value = Countv("Work", "NWCA7", "Processed")
    .Range("E21").Value = Countv("Work", "NWCA8", "Processed")
    .Range("E22").Value = Countv("Work", "NWCA9", "Processed")
    .Range("E23").Value = Countv("Work", "NWCA10A", "Processed")
    .Range("E24").Value = Countv("Work", "NWCA10B", "Processed")
    .Range("E32").Value = Countv("Work", "WSCA3", "Processed")
    .Range("E33").Value = Countv("Work", "WSCA4", "Processed")
    .Range("E34").Value = Countv("Work", "SECA14", "Processed")
    .Range("E35").Value = Countv("Work", "SECA15", "Processed")
    .Range("E36").Value = Countv("Work", "SECA16", "Processed")
End With
End Sub

Function Countv(v1 As String, v2 As String, Optional v3 As String = "") As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
    With Sheets("calculations")  
        Set rng1 = .Range("D7:D100000")
        Set rng2 = .Range("L7:L100000")
        Set rng3 = .Range("M7:M100000")
        If Len(v3) > 0 Then
            Countv = Application.CountIfs(rng1, v1, rng2, v2, rng3, v3)
        Else
            Countv = Application.CountIfs(rng1, v1, rng2, v2)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Maybe just `Set rng1 = .Range("D7:D100000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` and so on.

Comment: @barneyos. Hi, that didn't work unfortunately. I received Type Mismatch error below them on the first CountA row.

Comment: Now the first Countv row, I changed it from CountA.

Comment: Which line gets error ? Maybe after setting filtering there's nothing rows to display ? Try maybe add If statement like e.g. `If .AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count > 1 Then` before Set rng1 line.

Comment: @barneyos. This line gets the error Countv = Application.CountIfs(rng1, v1, rng2, v2, rng3, v3). I will try your suggestion tomorrow, cheers.